# Browser takes long time to render html controls asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ajax, iis-6

I have an aspx page showing lots of information in a tabular format on ajax tab container. Approximately 3 to 5 tabs are used. I have used some of AJAX controls such as CalendarExtendar, ValidationCallout etc on page. My problem is that the page is loaded fast but the browser takes long time for rendering the controls. On my local system the page loading takes around 8 seconds while on server it is taking about 25 seconds. I have also disabled the viewstate wherever applicable and even compressed the viewstate using gzip.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to instead of mentioning the used technologies as the first line, to put them in the tags.
This makes it searchable and comply to the conventions SO users expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried monitoring your call in firefox's [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) Net tab?
There you can dissect the transfer in detail and see what part of your page is taking how much time.
Also the [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) plugin will give you some sound advice on improving the performance of your pages.